# How can I smooth a square signal for digital input?

Tags: microcontroller

I have a 24V garage door motor attached to HDR1. The motor is powered with alternate polarity to open/close the door. I thought detecting the 'open' and 'close' movement would be as easy as checking the polarity, but it turns out the motor speed is controlled with square wave modulation, which obviously drives the MCU crazy.

How could I (easily) extend the circuit to 'smooth' that square wave to some decent 1/0 signal?

[image: current circuit]

Answer (score 1):

Why would a square wave signal into a uC "drive it crazy?"  Isn't that what all uC's use for at least some of its inputs and outputs?

I don't see any reason to process the input signal in a circuit; do it in software.

Detect the which input has transitions on it

Use a counter to determine if the frequency

Test this value against known-good limits

If the input signal is determined to be valid, then do whatever it is you want to do with the detected direction.

Answer (score 0):

> *How could I (easily) extend the circuit to 'smooth' that square wave
> to some decent 1/0 signal?*

You could use an analogue low-pass RC filter to remove the basic noise from the PWM. You could fit a capacitor straight after the 1 kΩ resistor in your circuit as a simple start and see if this works. Basically the capacitor connects between the cathode pins of the two opto-couplers.

A 10 μF capacitor will progressively filter signals above a frequency of 16 Hz and hopefully this will be sufficient to remove PWM artefacts.

Answer (score -1):

Since you are using an Wemos D1 mini that is based on the ESP-8266, there's a fair chance that you are using the Arduino environment.

If that's the case, all you need to do is use the [pulseIn](https://reference.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/advanced-io/pulsein/) method.

Set the `timeout` parameter to at least twice the length of one PWM pulse (from rising edge to rising edge) in microseconds.  If you get a 0 back then no pulse was detected.  Any other number is the duration of the pulse - the PWM signal is running.